# Subdomain Redirection Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain

So, I want to create a subdomain for each client like:

```
user1.mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/users/user1
```

or at least

```
user1.mydomain.com -> mydomain.com
```

and I can grab the `user1` part with php. Not a redirection, but a URL rewrite.

My problem is that this is just not working. This is my current configuration in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/users/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/users/%2/$1

# CodeIgniter Rules
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have seen many answers about this but in my case nothing seems to work. I have also updated my domain zones file:

```
*.mydomain.com.        A         000.000.000.000
```

What I see when typing something like `user2.mydomain.com` is an error page from my hosting account, not a server error. As usual, any help will be much appreciated, I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for days now :P

**Edit:** It seems that the problem is more with the server configuration (Apache). If I type any subdomain, what it shows is a page from my hosting provider's server, not a server error (like 500, etc), just a page. The same page shown if I just type my website's IP in the URL bar, it goes to the default page of my hosting provider.

Thank you all for reading.

Comment: You can't do this very well (or at all) on normal shared hosting. You'll need a real server for your own (e.g. a VPS), and _without_ any of that cPanel or Plesk crap.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the Apache server configuration?

Your `<VirtualHost>` needs a `ServerAlias` covering your subdomains or this won't work.

If you wanted, you could just serve the content out of the subdomains without redirecting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/docroot
    # existing config
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomains.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/docroot/users/%1
</VirtualHost>
```